# Expandable ListView shows the wrong title for the group position

Tags: android, expandablelistview

when I expand and collapse the groups in my expandable listview, the textview on it changes its text between all the other groups

this is my code:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GroupViewHolder vh = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_group_row, parent, false);
        vh = new GroupViewHolder();
        vh.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupHeader);
        convertView.setTag(R.string.tag_group);
    } else {
        vh = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.string.tag_group);
    }
    if(vh!=null) {
    vh.textView.setText(groupHeaders[groupPosition]);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

the children inside are correct, but the groups seem to change places (The textviews only, not their position)

how can I fix it?
ps. it happens only on android 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of your else case since view recycling is causing old headers to show up incorrectly.

Comment: what exactly do i need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and here is a working version:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolderGroupItem viewHolder;
    String groupTitle = Integer.toString((int)getGroup(groupPosition));

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderGroupItem();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_group_header, null);

        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_group_year);

        //  cache layout reference
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderGroupItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(groupTitle);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is view recycling. What you need to do is remove the `if (convertView == null)` portion from your code . use only `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_group_row, parent, false);
        vh = new GroupViewHolder();
        vh.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupHeader);
        convertView.setTag(R.string.tag_group);` then it will not check if the view is recyclable anymore and right views will remain at right position.